# how to send a bundle and start an activity after onclick

Tags: android

Hi guys I'm having a problem of sending a bundle to activity c and starting a new activity b after the button is clicked. The bundle is sent from a to c while after send activity a will go to activity b. This is the example code of mine:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(SelectYearActivity.this, AppointmentListActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("year_value", yearValue);
intent1.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent1);
startActivity(new Intent(SelectYearActivity.this, SelectMonthActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, First of all, your code the last line is out of reach, you have to properly start the activity, don't start two activity at the same place, as soon as you start one activity the next activity opens.

*the above information doesn't clearly specify what you want to achieve.*

it's not possible to go from 1st activity to 2nd & 3rd directly at once. you have to follow the stack.
1st -> 2nd -> 3rd
Here are the possible solutions:

1. pass the data form 1st -> 2nd ->3rd
2. use shared preference .
3. use Globals to pass the data to any activity.

You can pass any value between any two Activities you want. You just need to do two things:

In your FirstActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class);
i.putExtra("value_key", value); //valus is a String
startActivity(intent);
```

In your ThirdActivity's onCreate():

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = (String) b.getString("value_key");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code for sending data to another activity.

```
Intent were=new Intent(SelectYearActivity.this, AppointmentListActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("year_value", yearValue);
        were.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(were);
```

While Receiving data in next activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.AppointmentListActivity);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    n=b.getString("year_value");
```

I hope this will help to solve your error.